# Remove a key in hashmap when the value's hashset is Empty

Tags: java, hashmap, set, hashset

I have a hashmap that maps strings keys to hashsets values, and I want to remove a key from the hashmap when the hashmaps's hashset value is empty. I'm having trouble approaching this. Here's what I've tried but I'm very stuck:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, HashSet<Integer>> entr : stringIDMap.entrySet()) 
{  

                String key = entr.getKey();  

                if (stringIDMap.get(key).isEmpty())
                {

                    stringIDMap.remove(key);
                    continue;
                }
     //few print statements...
}
```

Comment: Can the value in hashmap i.e. HashSet<Integer> be null for some strings? What's the problem you are facing now?Getting NullPointer?

Answer (score 19):

In order to avoid [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html), you need to use the `Iterator` interface directly:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, HashSet<Integer>>> it = stringIDMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, HashSet<Integer>> e = it.next();
    String key = e.getKey();
    HashSet<Integer> value = e.getValue();
    if (value.isEmpty()) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

The reason your current code doesn't work is that you are attempting to remove elements from the map while iterating over it. When you call `stringIDMap.remove()`, this invalidates the iterator that the for-each loop uses under the cover, making further iteration impossible.

`it.remove()` solves this problem as it does not invalidate the iterator.

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 8, there is an excelent short solution with lambda:

```
stringIDMap.entrySet().removeIf(ent -> ent.getValue().isEmpty());
```

or you can use more concise way by passing method reference

`stringIDMap.values().removeIf(Set::isEmpty);`

Comment: better option stringIDMap.values().removeIf(Set::isEmpty);

Comment: Yes it's even shorter, thanks! Will add to my answer for more visability.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Iterator<String> iterator = mMapFiles.keySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        if ( mMapFiles.get( iterator.next() ).size() < 1 )
            iterator.remove();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped my project. Very simple and intuitive solution by Vahe!